# Jess issue about facts and rules

Tags: rule, jess

i use Jess rule engine with java and i have a template person with a number of facts. I excecute a rule concerning persons and i would like to get **the number of facts** that satisfy the rule and made it fire. Is this possible;
e.g.Command engine.executeCommand("(run)") returns only 0 or 1 in case a rule fired

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you need, there are several things you might do. The function `(run)` actually returns the number of rules that fired, so if each fact activates one rule, then the return value of `(run)` would do it.

If you need to do anything more complex, then you can register a [`JessEventListener`](http://www.jessrules.com/jess/docs/71/library.html#events) to be notified when each rule fires. The `JessEvent` will contain the whole activation record for the rule, so you can walk through it and count the facts however you like. Since rules can match the non-existence of facts, or the existence of *at least one* fact that fits a pattern, etc, the question of "how many facts activated a rule" isn't completely straightforward. But with the activation record in hand, you can count them however you like.

Comment: Thank you mr Hill, i solved the problem with (run),modifying my java code a little bit.